# pthread_cleanup_push and O2 CFLAGS

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads, setjmp, cflags

I have some warning when compiling a piece of code using **pthread_cleanup_push/pop** with -**O2** **CFLAGS**. Just by removing the O2 cflags in the Makefile make it compile without issue.

Is it forbidden to use gcc optimization with these pthread macros ? I was not able to find anything in man or documentation. By the way, is there any alternative to clean stuff at the end of a thread ? Also it is working perfectly with gcc arm. But not on x86 gcc.

Warning :

```
x/x.c:1292:2: warning: variable ‘__cancel_routine’ might be clobbered by ‘longjmp’ or ‘vfork’ [-Wclobbered]
  pthread_cleanup_push(x_cleanup, &fd);
```

My current CFLAGS option :

```
-W -Wall -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wextra  -Wno-unused-result,
-Wextra -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-missing-field-initializers
-std=gnu99 -O2
```

Comment: I assume you've seen [BZ 61118](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61118)?

Comment: @yugr  Yes I already saw this even if I was not sure if it was the reason. The bug was report on 2014... Its crazy... The only solution is to remove the Werror until a fix ? Roll back on a previous version of gcc on x86 ? It is not a deadlock to my code since the issue is not present with an ARM cross compiler. But I did want to be sure that its was not a bigger issue which can cause unexpected behavior of my code or bugs.

Comment: You could add `-Wno-clobbered` to your list of disabled warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been reported several times now in GCC tracker (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61118)). I believe that this warns about real issue in pthread.h (see [my comment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61118#c6)). `__cancel_routine` is not marked as volatile so it's value is indeed undefined after return via `longjmp` which may cause arbitrary consequences.

> The only solution is to remove the Werror until a fix ?

I'd rather go with `-Wno-clobbered`, to keep other warnings enabled.

> Roll back on a previous version of gcc on x86 ?

You'll have to rollback to pre-2014 times which is quite a change... I think that if the code works for you, just disable `-Wclobbered` (with a descriptive comment).

> But I did want to be sure that its was not a bigger issue which can cause unexpected behavior of my code or bugs.

Glibc code looks really suspicious. I'd wait for comments from GCC devs and if there is none, [report this to Glibc developers](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/).

Comment: FTR, at least for me this seems to be fixed by [this glibc commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=548f467fa14). Tested by copying the changed `pthread_cleanup_push` definition to `/usr/include/pthread.h` file on the older system where the issue arises and checking that compilation starts passing. So presumably modern Glibc has fixed the warning.

Comment: Okay, so I ended up adding a `#if ! __GLIBC_PREREQ(2, 33) /* Comment referring the commit goes */ #    pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wclobbered" #endif`